# iOTHub iOS framework randomly crashing SIGSEGV in xio_dowork

Tags: segmentation-fault, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

App crashes randomly when in background with a `SIGSEGV` type. Very hard to replicate but it happens when app is in background.

Log:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,3
Code Type:       arm64
Parent Process:   [1]

Date/Time:       2020-11-05T08:18:52.999Z
Launch Time:     2020-11-05T07:30:44Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 14.1 (18A8395)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x7e795d5f06c0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AzureIoTUtility                      0x0000000100ecab20 xio_dowork (xio.c:164)
1   AzureIoTuMqtt                        0x0000000100c6ce98 mqtt_client_dowork (mqtt_client.c:1296)
2   AzureIoTHubClient                    0x0000000100e27124 IoTHubTransport_MQTT_Common_DoWork (iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c:3229)
3   AzureIoTHubClient                    0x0000000100e0bc4c IoTHubClientCore_LL_DoWork (iothub_client_core_ll.c:2122)
4   Foundation                           0x000000018f895128 0x18f722000 + 1519912
5   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4b0050 0x18e411000 + 651344
6   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4afc50 0x18e411000 + 650320
7   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4af0c4 0x18e411000 + 647364
8   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a9178 0x18e411000 + 622968
9   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a84bc 0x18e411000 + 619708
10  GraphicsServices                     0x00000001a4fba820 0x1a4fb7000 + 14368
11  UIKitCore                            0x0000000190e55164 0x1902d6000 + 12054884
12  UIKitCore                            0x0000000190e5a840 0x1902d6000 + 12077120
13  Locate2u                             0x0000000100911b98 main (AppDelegate.swift:20)
14  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000018e16fe40 0x18e16f000 + 3648

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba670dd0 0x1ba66d000 + 15824
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4aecf8 0x18e411000 + 646392
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a8ea8 0x18e411000 + 622248
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a84bc 0x18e411000 + 619708
4   Foundation                           0x000000018f729e30 0x18f722000 + 32304
5   Foundation                           0x000000018f729d08 0x18f722000 + 32008
6   UIKitCore                            0x0000000190f05a4c 0x1902d6000 + 12778060
7   Foundation                           0x000000018f8940f0 0x18f722000 + 1515760
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d6421ca8 0x1d6420000 + 7336
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a788 0x1d6420000 + 42888

Thread 2:
0   Locate2u                             0x0000000100ab57c8 mach_exception_callback (PLCrashReporter.m:291)
1   Locate2u                             0x0000000100ac1320 exception_server_thread (PLCrashMachExceptionServer.m:770)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d6421ca8 0x1d6420000 + 7336
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a788 0x1d6420000 + 42888

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba670dd0 0x1ba66d000 + 15824
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4aecf8 0x18e411000 + 646392
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a8ea8 0x18e411000 + 622248
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a84bc 0x18e411000 + 619708
4   CFNetwork                            0x000000018ed64050 0x18eb21000 + 2371664
5   Foundation                           0x000000018f8940f0 0x18f722000 + 1515760
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d6421ca8 0x1d6420000 + 7336
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a788 0x1d6420000 + 42888

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba694c40 0x1ba66d000 + 162880
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d6421ca8 0x1d6420000 + 7336
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a788 0x1d6420000 + 42888

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba670dd0 0x1ba66d000 + 15824
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4aecf8 0x18e411000 + 646392
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a8ea8 0x18e411000 + 622248
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a84bc 0x18e411000 + 619708
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018e4a9590 0x18e411000 + 624016
5   CoreMotion                           0x0000000199287d50 0x199146000 + 1318224
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d6421ca8 0x1d6420000 + 7336
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a788 0x1d6420000 + 42888

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001ba6955bc 0x1ba66d000 + 165308
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001d642a77c 0x1d6420000 + 42876

Thread 0 crashed with arm64 Thread State:
   x21: 0x0000000100b09c56     x2: 0x000000011cd3fbb0    x16: 0x0000000100ecab18     x3: 0x0000000000000000
   x22: 0x000000011d80a060     x4: 0x00000000000062dc    x17: 0x000000004ea00000   cpsr: 0x0000000020000000
    x5: 0x000000011c92bdd0    x23: 0x000000018f8950e4     x6: 0x000000000000001c    x18: 0x000000010f2fd06c
   x10: 0x00000000000007fb     lr: 0x0000000100c6ce98     x7: 0x00000001ec58c890    x24: 0x0000000281d8fc18
   x11: 0x00000000000007fd     x8: 0x00007e795d5f0690    x19: 0x0000000281d8f780    x25: 0x000000011cd3fbc0
    x9: 0x000000000000006a    x12: 0x0000000000000001     fp: 0x000000016f4f1890    x26: 0x00000002828d1d40
   x13: 0x000000004e8b2867     pc: 0x0000000100ecab20    x27: 0x000000011cd3fbc0    x14: 0x000000004eab3000
   x20: 0x000000011cd3fbb0     x0: 0x0000000281aa0067     sp: 0x000000016f4f1860    x28: 0x00000001e2b73000
   x15: 0x0000000000000166     x1: 0x0000000000000000

Binary Images:
0x000000010090c000 -        0x0000000100b37fff +Locate2u arm64  <19557f44ea61300487c74c984f4e00f6> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Locate2u
0x0000000100c64000 -        0x0000000100c6ffff +AzureIoTuMqtt arm64  <695fed86890a3e288a3441dfd18e7032> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/AzureIoTuMqtt.framework/AzureIoTuMqtt
0x0000000100c80000 -        0x0000000100c87fff +LightweightObservable arm64  <f92054b46bba331faa7ca25175e4e358> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/LightweightObservable.framework/LightweightObservable
0x0000000100d8c000 -        0x0000000100dabfff +AppAuth arm64  <daefff97647e311e8f3a07f8663e1df2> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth
0x0000000100df0000 -        0x0000000100e5ffff +AzureIoTHubClient arm64  <c816257d2178378cb15b2a99bf0a67fd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/AzureIoTHubClient.framework/AzureIoTHubClient
0x0000000100eac000 -        0x0000000100ed3fff +AzureIoTUtility arm64  <8f6679548f5732bfb0939dea6daacdbf> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/AzureIoTUtility.framework/AzureIoTUtility
0x0000000100ef8000 -        0x0000000100f37fff +AzureIoTuAmqp arm64  <a5e04435055b36de888416787b037210> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/AzureIoTuAmqp.framework/AzureIoTuAmqp
0x0000000100f68000 -        0x000000010100bfff +Bond arm64  <f22424cb20f533bf9935a827a6569416> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Bond.framework/Bond
0x000000010117c000 -        0x00000001011e7fff +Branch arm64  <caf1dd07c54d3879a1b61ca9f83579fd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Branch.framework/Branch
0x00000001012a4000 -        0x00000001012c7fff +Differ arm64  <c14c0e2324e63784ac8e61cede9d3b2a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Differ.framework/Differ
0x0000000101310000 -        0x000000010131bfff +GradientLoadingBar arm64  <c7cd0e9dbdfa3d49b952056f005f258d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/GradientLoadingBar.framework/GradientLoadingBar
0x0000000101338000 -        0x0000000101347fff +GrowingTextView arm64  <68f854a3e2593a179465faa64e204850> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/GrowingTextView.framework/GrowingTextView
0x0000000101368000 -        0x00000001013abfff +IQKeyboardManagerSwift arm64  <33356026bbc836fcb6ef89118cda3182> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift
0x0000000101448000 -        0x0000000101453fff +JWTDecode arm64  <bdb5af0893fb3ee483f728b375cb0b20> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/JWTDecode.framework/JWTDecode
0x0000000101470000 -        0x0000000101507fff +Kingfisher arm64  <3d7b9176fb6737e3b764423fb0743712> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Kingfisher.framework/Kingfisher
0x0000000101654000 -        0x000000010168ffff +Mustache arm64  <21d4a5f617e7303fb36d4853883b9a2f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Mustache.framework/Mustache
0x00000001016fc000 -        0x0000000101707fff +Polyline arm64  <b809e00750513640841452b33a574ffc> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Polyline.framework/Polyline
0x0000000101720000 -        0x000000010172ffff +Queuer arm64  <bb9d99f2d41d3a4caa70d69128d885fc> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Queuer.framework/Queuer
0x0000000101758000 -        0x0000000101763fff +Reachability arm64  <3cc87015b0e937df8bab741de3fb78af> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
0x0000000101788000 -        0x00000001017ebfff +ReactiveKit arm64  <d95942a6b82f3287b1dca578cae65760> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/ReactiveKit.framework/ReactiveKit
0x00000001018c8000 -        0x00000001018ebfff +SideMenu arm64  <7138b0d583cd3063a71296bc837385fe> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/SideMenu.framework/SideMenu
0x0000000101958000 -        0x0000000101973fff +Siren arm64  <8d93ba4fcb953ae7bc37abe952275c26> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Siren.framework/Siren
0x00000001019bc000 -        0x00000001019cffff +SwiftSignatureView arm64  <446677888a303cbfa38877d1c71f3697> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/SwiftSignatureView.framework/SwiftSignatureView
0x0000000101a04000 -        0x0000000101a27fff +Swinject arm64  <6a1314501cad337e9f75dbe8e5329126> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Swinject.framework/Swinject
0x0000000101a70000 -        0x0000000101ae3fff +SwinjectAutoregistration arm64  <801fdc8117083470b678a9cdc00e43dd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/SwinjectAutoregistration.framework/SwinjectAutoregistration
0x0000000101b24000 -        0x0000000101b2ffff +SwinjectStoryboard arm64  <854bcc4cbe27343fb694fc269cfc5de3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/SwinjectStoryboard.framework/SwinjectStoryboard
0x0000000101b50000 -        0x0000000101b8bfff +Tatsi arm64  <d8a4297e17c434caafe3bedec034855c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Tatsi.framework/Tatsi
0x0000000101bec000 -        0x0000000101c0bfff +Valet arm64  <ada28bb79c0f348aa7a499d89eb525e8> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4A80C9-2D46-4D90-9C89-574836896A92/Locate2u.app/Frameworks/Valet.framework/Valet
0x000000018e16f000 -        0x000000018e1a8fff  libdyld.dylib arm64  <9b2d02a4c9c03cafbbd2c1bcee117e8e> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x000000018e411000 -        0x000000018e7c4fff  CoreFoundation arm64  <52963dbafa8936c2826228b9776f8c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x000000018eb21000 -        0x000000018efaefff  CFNetwork arm64  <89f0f3290648327eb82d22ab5bbb3298> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x000000018f722000 -        0x000000018f9d0fff  Foundation arm64  <e39926acf2d931cd9585deba71b6dc97> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x00000001902d6000 -        0x0000000191716fff  UIKitCore arm64  <432c7d5453153ec7a3bea48e873736a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x0000000199146000 -        0x00000001993a5fff  CoreMotion arm64  <10c0abfc00f33989b9819c3635d6249a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x00000001a4fb7000 -        0x00000001a4fbffff  GraphicsServices arm64  <bc5f92df72a337c5b5ddd1cade629003> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x00000001ba66d000 -        0x00000001ba69dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <7db928dd0ada38ce9384b87fbe286f80> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x00000001d6420000 -        0x00000001d642bfff  libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <5120f238ca4e3e54952b67814d3c744a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Comment: Tracked on github here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1747

I recommend to close the question and follow the github issue instead. See also Stackoverflow question guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already being tracked as a github issue